# java.lang.NullPointerException error in methods

Tags: java

What is causing my error???

```
public class Keyboard {
    private Scanner keyboard;

    /**
     * Default contructor
     */
    public void keyboard() {
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * get and return an int
     * @return an int
     */
    public int getInt() {
        int myInt;
        myInt = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        return myInt;
    }
}

public class TestKeyboard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter an int: ");
        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
        keyboard.getInt();
    }
}
```

I am currently getting the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at Keyboard.getInt(Keyboard.java:27)
>       at TestKeyboard.main(TestKeyboard.java:6)

Comment: `keyboard` (the `Scanner`) is `null`.  You seem to have mistaken the constructor for a method `public void keyboard() {` probably should be `public Keyboard() {`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Did you bother to read any of the answers given below, which answered the question before you marked as duplicate?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I did, and the question should have been marked as a duplicate earlier, as we don't need to contently keep answering `NullPointerException` questions, but should be encouraging developers to develop good debugging skills instead.  This question has been answered before and doesn't/shouldn't be answered again (and don't get me started on my opinion of the answer)

Comment: I agree with you, but because so much time elapsed and no moderator marked as a duplicate, I decided to answer it (q.v. below).  In any case, in a few months I will have some admin rights, then I will also be able to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You should be able to "vote to close" now, but I think you need +100K to "hammer" close (not my favorite power by the way)

Comment: Rats...I'm about 2-3 years out from breaking 100K.  By then, half the planet will have a rep of 100K :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is no default constructor . The constructor should be `public KeyBoard()`. The Keyboard class has a `keyboard()` method that you are considering as constructor.

Comment: can some explain the downvote !